# Eliminate Records based on Value that can exist in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm relatively new to SQL (Using Sql Server).  I have a table that possesses account information and 10 columns, each which store various error codes.  The problem is that I need to eliminate records if at least one of the error codes I provide in a list exists in any one of those 10 columns.

For instance, If the numbers 98 and 99 are found in either Column1 or Column2 or Column3 and so on, then I want to exclude them from my result set.

Specifically, someone's is transitioning their stored procedure logic to me, but the piece of code which allegedly handles this problem does not do what it is supposed to (unless I'm missing something obvious).  The code is below and is in the where clause.

```
Select * From arcu.arcuaccountdetailed ad
Where
(Case
when ad.AccountWarningcode1 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1 
when ad.AccountWarningcode2 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode3 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode4 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode5 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode6 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode7 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode8 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode9 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode10 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode11 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode12 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode13 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode14 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode15 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode16 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode17 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode18 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode19 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
when ad.AccountWarningcode20 IN (98,99,2,29,30,21,10,11,50,53,97) then 1
Else 0 End) = 1
```

I would greatly appreciate any insight.

Comment: What is this `= 1` supposed to be?

Comment: Can you show us the full query?  What is not working?

Comment: Grzegorz, frankly I don't think this entire piece of code makes any sense at all, but my colleague insists otherwise.  I'd like to approach this problem correctly.

Comment: This is the full query:

Comment: Your code should be doing what you expect.

Comment: Added the full query above:  the problem is this logic is supposed to eliminate records when the list of values in the IN statement exist in ANY one of these columns, but I've found multiple instances where this code still returns these values.

Comment: I apologize if I'm not explaining this clearly enough:  If I add accountwarningcode1 to the select, this piece of code returns several of the values in the list which wish to eliminate.

Comment: This logic is only going to return records where one of those columns contain one of those values. I think the WHERE logic is doing the exact opposite of what you want. If you want to exclude a row if AccountWarningcode1 or AccountWarningcode2 or ... equals 98 or 99 or... then the `= 1` at the end should be `= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the data!  Whenever there are columns in a table with numeric suffices, the data model is suspect.  Oh, sometimes that is useful, but your problem clearly shows why this is an issue.  You want a separate table with one row per `AccountWarningCode`.

One thing you can do is a clever application of `cross apply`:

```
select ad.*
from arcu.arcuaccountdetailed ad cross apply
     (select max(case when v.AccountWarningCode in  (98, 99, 2, 29, 30, 21, 10, 11, 50, 53, 97) 
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) as flag
      from (values (ad.AccountWarningcode1),
                   (ad.AccountWarningcode2),
                   . . .
           ) v(AccountWarningCode)
     ) awc
where awc.flag = 1
```

This might not fix your specific problem -- it implements the logic in the question.  But it should give a better handle on the code and prevent typos in different parts of the conditions.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I'm not really sure how to apply this solution to my problem, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: @MarkFallone . . . What part of the query do you not understand how to apply?